# Android Usage of Call Intent on Samsung Galaxy-S

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I am using following to make a call:

```
Deal dealInfo = getDealInfo();
........    
    ImageView callToVendor = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.callvendor);
                callToVendor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + dealInfo.getVendor().getPhone()));
                            startActivityForResult(intent,1);

                        }
                });
```

It is working fine on HTC and some Samsung sets but having problem on Samsung Galaxy-S set. Any idea?

Comment: What's the problem? Nothing happen? Throw exception? Call to wrong number?

Comment: I get no caller id on the call screen although I have debugged the code and the uri returned is properly formatted.

Comment: How about call log? Is the number shown correctly? Or empty?

Comment: The dialler number field remains empty.

Comment: Have no idea about the cause. Did you try ACTION_DIAL and does it paste the dial number into dialer correctly?

Comment: Yes i have used this, but same response